# What does literal refer to?

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs

Hello I am new to blockchain. I was reading solidity docs and they were continuously repeating the word "literal", what does this word mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: Constant value, like `42` or `"xyz"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literals refer to fixed values that the program may not alter during its execution. These fixed values are also called constants. Generally, both terms, constants and literals are used interchangeably.